# Where does Appcelerator Studio pull down Android sdk files BEFORE it installs them?

Tags: android, appcelerator-studio

I'm using Axway Appcelerator Studio, build: 5.0.0.201712081732

On the studio dashboard, I click Download under Android and I see Android is (still) "not yet configured"

I click Configure and accept the license it jumps to installing, it doesn't ask me what to install, nor do I see it downloading files.

When it 'completes', it displays

Latest Version installed: Unknown
Current Version installed: Unknown
Installed Location: /Users/jwheat/Library/Android/sdk  <--- doesn't exit

During a previous attempt, I ran my drive out of space, so I think the 'setup' version of the SDKs is corrupt, and needs to be removed, it is clearly still somewhere because studio isn't downloading anything. (I've since resolved the space issue)

Any idea where Studio temporarily stores these files so I can manually delete them?

-Jon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix will be available with https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-9035

And, we have seen it's getting installed into the following location sometimes.

> /Applications/Appcelerator
>   Studio/AppceleratorStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/